# Serializing Object with nested classes return empty String Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Im new to kotlin and android development. Im currently trying to get a POST request to a django REST-API in my local server. Im using Retrofit 2 and Gson for http request and JSON.

I have a class for POST body (DataPost) and goes like this:

```
class DataPost(_type: String, _attributes: Item) {
    @SerializedName("type")
    var type: String? = null


    @SerializedName("attributes")
    var attributes: Item? = null

}
class Item(_userId: Int, _dbId: Int, _title: String, _body: String){
    @SerializedName("userdId")
    var userdId: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("dbId")
    var dbId: Int = 0
    @SerializedName("title")
    var title: String? = null
    @SerializedName("body")
    var body: String? = null


    companion object {
        fun className(): String {return "Item"}
    }

}
```

When I initialize it and try to serialize it and log it to JSON by:

```
var item: Item = Item(1,2,"Shiee","shie body")
var data: DataPost = DataPost("Item", item)
Log.i(TAG_LOGS, Gson.toJson(data))
```

I just get this output:

```
{}
```

And no error in console/log. So I assume its not seriliazing it property due the nested object, but as anything, I might be wrong. Why is returning an empty JSON my DataPost Object?

EDIT: Expected JSON:

```
{
            "type": "Item",
            "attributes": {
                "userdId": 1,
                "dbId": 2,
                "title": "Shiee",
                "body": "shiee body"
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I just needed to delete de ? operator that marks the type as nullable since I didn't declare a serialization for nullable.

From:

```
@SerializedName("type")
var type: String? = null


@SerializedName("attributes")
var attributes: Item? = null
```

To:

```
@SerializedName("type")
lateinit var type: String

@SerializedName("attributes")
lateinit var attributes: Item
```

Comment: Good job solving the problem and updating us with the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The arguments you pass to your classes are not used in any way.
For example, in `DataPost` you have `_type` as an argument in the constructor, and `type` as a property in the class. These two **unrelated**. So when you do

```
DataPost("Item", item)
```

`"Item"` and `item` are passed in the constructor as `_type` and `_attributes`, but then they're not used: in particular they **are not** automatically assigned to `type` and `attributes`.

I'm not sure how changing the types of the properties from nullable to non-nullble types is helping you, as it shouldn't.

What you need to do instead is either move your `var`s directly to the constructor or manually assign them.
Using your `DataPost` class as an example. You can either do:

```
class DataPost(
    @SerializedName("type")
    var type: String?,
    @SerializedName("attributes")
    var attributes: Item?
}
```

or

```
class DataPost(_type: String, _attributes: Item) {
    @SerializedName("type")
    var type: String? = _type


    @SerializedName("attributes")
    var attributes: Item? = _attributes

}
```

Side note: if these are immutable values you can change `var` to `val`.

Comment: Yeah you are also right, I changed that to have an init() that asigns the _var to the correspondig field. But the real problem was that Gson library doesn't serialize null types by default. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Gson is a Java library and in Java all types are always nullable. Probably you mean that Gson ignores null values when serializing, i.e. it won't output `{"type":null}`, but `{}`. If you want that you can simply build a Gson instance that will do so `val gson = GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()`. But if the value is not null it doesn't matter if the Kotlin type is nullable or not.